# Inputting data to Excel efficiently

Tags: c#, excel

I need to write data from my system to Excel. It needs to be spread out over 7 sheets, and 300,000 lines of data (each line of my data is about 10 cells). It takes about 5 minutes to write the data. I was wondering if anyone could advise me on how to make it more efficient.

Right now, for each line of my data,I access the workbook and write out the data.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

    app = new Excel.Application();
    workBook = app.Workbooks.Add();

    InitTable(dt1);
    InitTable(dt2);
    AddRowsToTable(dt1);
    AddRowsToTable(dt2);
    AddSheet(dt1);
    AddSheet(dt2);

    workBook.SaveAs(path);

}

void AddSheet(DataTable table)
{
    Excel.Worksheet workSheet;

    workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.Add();

    // Add columns
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        workSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    }

    // Add rows
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < table.Rows.Count; iRow++)
    {
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < table.Columns.Count; iCol++)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol + 1] = table.Rows[iRow][iCol];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could go for an OleDbConnection, where you could write more efficiently (using it as a database in a sense)

Comment: Although it is a lot harder to use, I think the [openxml library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is much more performant than the library you are using.

Comment: since omepXML is so hard to use you should use ClosedXML. It is a wrapper for [OpenXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Inserting%20Data&referringTitle=Documentation) that makes it WAY simpler.

Comment: this is slowly becoming an opinion based topic :D

Comment: I'm with Brad. Another benefit is that you don't actually need excel installed for it to work. It api can also take input from DataTable, DataSet or DataReader, so the impact to your application would be minimal [closedxml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Take a look at the EPPlus library. http://epplus.codeplex.com/ I've found it to be really good.  Or if you want to continue with interop, you can add your data to a 2d array and then do a single write to Excel.  The slow thing with what you are doing is all the individual write operations via COM.

Answer (score 2):

Use EPPlus, it is 10 times easier to use than anything else I have come across.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
  ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Accounts");
  ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
  pck.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/releases/view/197852) library. It is a wrapper for OpenXML but OpenXML is horrendously difficult to use. Because it is a wrapper you do need to reference OpenXML still but you get [NuGet it](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/).

Open/ClosedXML also does not need to instantiate Excel to create files like Interop does so you do not need Excel installed. It just makes the XML structure which is acceptable to Excel.

Here's an example of adding data. `worksheet.Cell("A1").InsertData()` takes any IEnumerable.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyData> md = new List<MyData>();
        md.Add(new MyData() {col1="abc", col2="123", col3="xyz" });
        md.Add(new MyData() { col1 = "ABC", col2 = "gth", col3 = "DDD" });
        md.Add(new MyData() { col1 = "45df", col2 = "987", col3 = "BUR" });


        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
        worksheet.Cell("A1").InsertData(md);

        workbook.SaveAs(@"C:/mydata.xlsx");
    }

}

public class MyData
{
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
}
```

Gives me an Excel document that looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Aspose Cells for .NET. Simple and easy to use. 
Here is an example:

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // The path to the documents directory.
        string dataDir = Path.GetFullPath("../../../Data/");

        //Specify your desired matrix
        int rowsCount = 10000;
        int colsCount = 30;

        var workbook = new Workbook();
        var ooxmlSaveOptions = new OoxmlSaveOptions();

        ooxmlSaveOptions.LightCellsDataProvider = new TestDataProvider(workbook, rowsCount, colsCount);

        workbook.Save(dataDir+ "output.xlsx", ooxmlSaveOptions);
    }
}

class TestDataProvider : LightCellsDataProvider
{
    private int _row = -1;
    private int _column = -1;

    private int maxRows;
    private int maxColumns;

    private Workbook _workbook;
    public TestDataProvider(Workbook workbook, int maxRows, int maxColumns)
    {
        this._workbook = workbook;
        this.maxRows = maxRows;
        this.maxColumns = maxColumns;
    }

    #region LightCellsDataProvider Members

    public bool IsGatherString()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public int NextCell()
    {
        ++_column;
        if (_column < this.maxColumns)
            return _column;
        else
        {
            _column = -1;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    public int NextRow()
    {
        ++_row;
        if (_row < this.maxRows)
        {
            _column = -1;
            return _row;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public void StartCell(Cell cell)
    {
        cell.PutValue(_row + _column);
        if (_row == 1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            cell.Formula = "=Rand() + A2";
        }
    }

    public void StartRow(Row row)
    {
    }

    public bool StartSheet(int sheetIndex)
    {
        if (sheetIndex == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    #endregion
}
```